# How to store response when http client closed a connection?

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, falconframework

I'm using falcon framework in python to form json responses of web api.

For instance I have a function called `logic()` that works for 30-90min. I want something like this:

1. When http-client asks for /api/somepath.json we call
   `somepath_handle()`
2. `somepath_handle()` runs `logic()` in another thread/process
3. When `logic()` is finished, thread is closed
4. `somepath_handle()` reads response of `logic()` from return
5. If `somepath_handle()` was killed before `logic()` was finished, then thread/etc with `logic()` isn't stopped until it is finished

The code:

```
def somepath_handle():
    run_async_logic()
    response=wait_for_async_logic_response() # read response of logic()
    return_response(response)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a simple worker to create the queue where I am processing some commands. If add simple response storage than there will be possibility to process any requests and not loss them when connection was lost.

Example:
It's main function that used falconframework.org to response to requests.

main.py:

```
from flow import Flow
import falcon
import threading
import storage

__version__ = 0.1
__author__ = 'weldpua2008@gmail.com'


app = falcon.API(
    media_type='application/json')

app.add_route('/flow', Flow())

THREADS_COUNT = 1
# adding the workers to process queue of command
worker = storage.worker
for _ in xrange(THREADS_COUNT):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
```

It's simple storage with worker code
storage.py:

```
from Queue import Queue
import subprocess
import logging
main_queque = Queue()

def worker():
    global main_roles_queque
    while True:
        try:
            cmd = main_queque.get()
            #do_work(item)
            #time.sleep(5)
            handler = subprocess.Popen(
            cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
            stdout, stderr = handler.communicate()
            logging.critical("[queue_worker]: stdout:%s, stderr:%s, cmd:%s" %(stdout, stderr, cmd))
            main_queque.task_done()
        except Exception as error:
            logging.critical("[queue_worker:error] %s" %(error))
```

It's class that will process any requests [POST, GET]
flow.py:

```
import storage
import json
import falcon
import random

class Flow(object):

    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        storage_value = storage.main_queque.qsize()
        msg = {"qsize": storage_value}
        resp.body = json.dumps(msg, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200

    #curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}'  http://10.206.102.81:8888/flow
    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        r = random.randint(1, 10000000000000)
        cmd = 'sleep 1;echo "ss %s"' % str(r)
        storage.main_queque.put(cmd)
        storage_value = cmd
        msg = {"value": storage_value}
        resp.body = json.dumps(msg, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200
```

Answer (score 1):

If your process takes such a long time, I advise you to send the result to the user using email, or maybe a live notification system ?

Comment: Most responses take less then 40 seconds but if there are network issues - can be hours.

Comment: Also it runs as a service on computer so it's only one way to delivery a response.